# How to write Unpivot query within Main Query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, unpivot

I have a main query and in there there are columns that are bringing in data. I need to convert those columns into single column but be able to keep other elements in the query as is. Its writing UNPIVOT data query with the main to convert these individual columns.

From below query, STRING_ATTR1 through STRING_ATTR20 (all 20) needs to be UNPIVOT and presented as 2 columns one that contains "String Names" (i.e. STRING_ATTR1, STRING_ATTR2, etc) and 2nd column "String Data" that contains the actual unpivoted data.

Please help!

```
SELECT
[AGG_ELEMENT].[I_COUNT] AS [ELEMENT I COUNT],
[AGG_ELEMENT].[E_TIME_SUM] AS [ELEMENT E TIME],
[AGG_ELEMENT].[A_TIME_SUM] AS [ELEMENT A TIME],
[AGG_ELEMENT].[I_TIME_SUM] AS [ELEMENT I TIME],
[AGG_ELEMENT].[O_COUNT] AS [OPS COUNT],
[AGG_ELEMENT].[R_TIME_SUM] AS [R TIME],
[AGG_ELEMENT].[M_COUNT] AS [MSG COUNT],
[AGG_ELEMENT].[SE_COUNT] AS [SE COUNT],
[AGG_ELEMENT].[UE_COUNT] AS [UE COUNT],
[USERS].[ID] AS [USER ID],
[USERS].[LOGIN] AS [USER LOGIN],
[USERS].[DOMAIN] AS [USER DOMAIN],
[USERS].[NAME] AS [USER NAME],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR1] AS [STRING_ATTR1],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR2] AS [STRING_ATTR2],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR3] AS [STRING_ATTR3],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR4] AS [STRING_ATTR4],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR5] AS [STRING_ATTR5],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR6] AS [STRING_ATTR6],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR7] AS [STRING_ATTR7],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR8] AS [STRING_ATTR8],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR9] AS [STRING_ATTR9],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR10] AS [STRING_ATTR10],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR11] AS [STRING_ATTR11],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR12] AS [STRING_ATTR12],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR13] AS [STRING_ATTR13],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR14] AS [STRING_ATTR14],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR15] AS [STRING_ATTR15],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR16] AS [STRING_ATTR16],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR17] AS [STRING_ATTR17],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR18] AS [STRING_ATTR18],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR19] AS [STRING_ATTR19],
[USERS].[STRING_ATTR20] AS [STRING_ATTR20],
[DAY].[TIMESTAMP] AS [DATE DAY],
[COMPUTER].[DOMAIN_NAME] AS [DOMAIN NAME],
[COMPUTER].[COMPUTER_NAME] AS [COMPUTER NAME],
[APPLICATION].[NAME] AS [APPLICATION NAME],
[MODULE].[NAME] AS [MODULE NAME],
[SCREEN].[NAME] AS [SCREEN NAME],
[SCREEN_TYPE].[NAME] AS [SCREEN TYPE]
FROM [AGG_ELEMENT] [AGG_ELEMENT]
LEFT JOIN [USERS] [USERS] ON ([AGG_ELEMENT].[USER_ID] = [USERS].[ID])
LEFT JOIN [DAY] [DAY] ON ([AGG_ELEMENT].[DAY_ID] = [DAY].[ID])
LEFT JOIN [COMPUTER] [COMPUTER] ON ([AGG_ELEMENT].[COMPUTER_ID] = [COMPUTER].[ID])
LEFT JOIN [APPLICATION] [APPLICATION] ON ([AGG_ELEMENT].[APPLICATION_ID] = [APPLICATION].[ID])
LEFT JOIN [MODULE] [MODULE] ON ([AGG_ELEMENT].[MODULE_ID] = [MODULE].[ID])
LEFT JOIN [SCREEN] [SCREEN] ON ([AGG_ELEMENT].[SCREEN_ID] = [SCREEN].[ID])
LEFT JOIN [SCREEN_TYPE] [SCREEN_TYPE] ON ([AGG_ELEMENT].[SCREEN_TYPE] = [SCREEN_TYPE].[ID])
WHERE
[DAY].[TIMESTAMP] BETWEEN '10/1/2019' AND '12/31/2019'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT v.*, . . .
FROM . . . OUTER APPLY
     (VALUES ('ATTR1', USERS.STRING_ATTR1),
             ('ATTR2', USERS.STRING_ATTR2),
             ('ATTR3', USERS.STRING_ATTR3),
              . . .
     ) v(which, val)
WHERE [DAY].[TIMESTAMP] BETWEEN '2019-10-01' AND '2019-12-31'
```

Comment: Sorry I am lost - how and where would i apply OUTER APPLY? within the main query? please point me in right direction. Thanks.

Comment: @JoeCooper . . . In the `FROM` clause, after all the `JOIN`s.

Comment: Understood -so next I would need to add (which, val) columns to the select statement in order to view the data right?

Comment: @JoeCooper . . . Yes.  Just include the columns in the `select`.

Comment: Will this increase my number of records count - as in duplicate data? or not?

Comment: @JoeCooper . . . Yes.  An additional row for every value being unpivoted.  If you want to filter some out -- say `NULL` values -- than add a condition to the `WHERE` clause (such as `v.val IS NOT NULL`).

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff - this works like a charm (minus the amount of records created).